# Labview Time Stamp Recording

Tags: loops, time, labview

I have a data loop in my LabView GUI, that records sensor data. There is a time stamp in the data coming from my DAQ (tick count) but I'm trying to align data to one universal time stamp (My High speed loop runs at 20kHz, and the low speed loop at 500Hz). So I made a local variable from the highest speed loop in my DAQ, and injected it into my slower loop, thinking that it would only record the timestamp once every time the loop executes. I was right, but the timestamp is a packet of 816 timestamps... So my data looks like this:

data.......time
0..........time
0..........time
...
data.......time

I know how to parse this with Matlab, but I need to correct it in LabView. how can I get only one time stamp per loop iteration from the 816 datapoints? the alignment appears to be that the data is read at the end of the time stamp packet...

Edit: I tried using the Size_of_array.vi and an indexing vi as shown below, but my fear is that it will fill the array of the 500ms loop with only one time stamp. Sorry, I'm restricted as to how much code I can show.

[image: time loop]

Comment: Please attach some relevant code.

Comment: @Dave_St, I'm restricted as to how much I'm allowed to show, but I did post something.

Comment: It looks like you're creating an array of identical "timestamps" but really you only need one right?

Comment: @Dave_St this loop runs at 500Hz, the incoming packets contain as much data, so I'd need an array of time stamps to be created once per loop cycle, no?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your requirements and your issue is still not clear to me. All I know for sure is that you're creating an array filled with identical values when you use "initialize array". Why do you need 500 copies of the same value?

Comment: Can you prepare and post a code snippet that demonstrates the problem, or at a minimum an example of the data you're currently getting compared to what you want (e.g. as a screenshot of the LabVIEW indicators, suitably resized so we can see enough data)? I don't understand the requirement or what is going wrong from what you've posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

Which DAQ module do you use? Why don't you read Waveform data type from the device? If you'd read Waveform, and it is some cDAQ module, then you will have all timestamps data. Afterwards, you could "align" timestamps of data from different modules manually (unless, you use triggered acquisition, and in that case timestamps should be aligned already).
You can't really synchronize timestamps using local variable, because you could get into race condition.
Did you check LabVIEW examples for DAQ signals acquisition? Especially, about synchronization of two modules? Maybe, it could help you; but without the code it is difficult to say, how to solve your issue...